# Can we adopt Booleans to Java8 like Optionals (ifPresent and orElse)

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

Using Java8, this could be done:

```
Optional.ofNullable(realResult).orElse(mockResult);
```

instead of:

```
if(realResult == null)
    return mockResult;
return realResult;
```

---

**Question:** Could we adobt Booleans to java8? or in other words, can we write something like that:

```
Boolean.valueOf(boolVar).ifTrue(trueResult).orElse(falseResult);
```

instead of:

```
if(boolVar)
    return trueResult;
return falseResult;
```

**Edit #1**
Thanks for suggesting ternary operations, still wondering if we can?

Comment: Whats wrong with `return boolVar ? trueResult : falseResult`?.

Comment: You can create your own class with such behavior, it is not hard to to

Comment: @ParkerHalo nothing wrong, thanks for that, still wondering if we can adopt boolean or not?

Comment: @ByeBye how? does java support extensions?

Comment: You have to create custom wrapper `BooleanWrapper` which will provide methods

Comment: @AhmedGhoneim Java does not support class extensions like C# does, but you can create an extended subclass and add the methods you like.

Comment: @ParkerHalo `public final class Boolean` ... so the best you could do is wrap in a decorator.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about using the **terniary operator** that's already included in the language?

```
boolVar ? trueResult : falseResult
```

**EDIT:** that's how it would look like if you really want such a class:

```
public class Conditional<T> {

    private final boolean condition;
    private T valueWhenTrue;

    public static Conditional valueOf(boolean condition) {
        return new Conditional(condition);
    }

    private Conditional(boolean condition) {
        this.condition = condition;
    }

    public Conditional ifTrue(T valueWhenTrue) {
        this.valueWhenTrue = valueWhenTrue;
        return this;
    }

    public T orElse(T valueWhenFalse) {
        return condition ? valueWhenTrue : valueWhenFalse;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Conditional.valueOf(boolVar).ifTrue(trueResult).orElse(falseResult)
```

Comment: thanks for that, still wondering if we can adopt boolean or not?

Comment: @AhmedGhoneim no, you would need extension methods for that and Java does not support this

Comment: `ifTrue` should return `valueWhenTrue` no ?

Comment: But, it is actually not working like `Optional`, it will be better if `ifTrue` method will return `Optional` type

Comment: @azro: `ifTrue` cannot return the value (or null), as the result needs to retain the original condition (boolean) as well as provide the `orElse` method - that's another point why such a class wouldn't be elegant. This solution really only works when using both `ifTrue` followed by `orElse`.

Answer (score 5):

`java.lang.Boolean` does not have a an `ifTrue()` method.

You could write your own implementation of `Boolean` and make it do whatever you like, but I don't see why you wouldn't use existing patterns around handling booleans, which work perfectly well.

There are loads of weird and wonderful possibilities:

```
 return Stream.of(Boolean.valueOf(b))
     .filter(Function.identity())
     .map( b -> trueResult)
     .findAny()
     .orElse( falseResult);

 ----

 return Optional.of(b)
     .filter(function.identity())
     .map( b -> trueResult)
     .orElse(falseResult);
```

... but why would you when a ternary operator using the primitive is clearer, shorter and more efficient both in both memory and operations:

```
 return b ? trueResult : falseResult;
```

Comment: I know ifTrue() is not in Boolean class, can I add it, with something like C# extensions?

Comment: You can't extend `Boolean` because it is marked `final`. Java has nothing analogous to C# extensions. There are JVM based languages that have similar features (Groovy, Scala, ...) but not Java itself.

Answer (score 2):

I won't do that in my code, but because you ask, you can use stream and this kind of operation

*2 examples :*

```
private static String boolString(boolean boolVar) {
    return Stream.of(boolVar).filter(b -> b).map(x -> "foo").findFirst().orElse("bar");
}
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
private static int boolInt(boolean boolVar) {
    return Stream.of(boolVar).filter(b -> b).map(x -> 1).findFirst().orElse(0);
}
```

---

To be used like :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(boolInt(true));       //1
    System.out.println(boolInt(false));      //0
    System.out.println(boolString(true));    //foo
    System.out.println(boolString(false));   //bar
}
```

---

But `ternary-operator` or classic `if` stays easier to use

Answer (score 1):

You can create something like this:

```
public class Wrap<T> {

    private final boolean value;

    public Wrap(final boolean value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Optional<T> ifTrue(final T ob) {
        if(value) {
            return Optional.ofNullable(ob);
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }

}
```

And:

```
public final class BooleanWraper {

    private BooleanWraper() {

    }

    public static <T> Wrap<T> valueOf(final boolean value) {
        return new Wrap<>(value);
    }

}
```

And then use it:

```
final String value = BooleanWraper.<String>valueOf(true)
    .ifTrue("true")
    .orElse("false");
```

It is using `Optional` in the end.